# new C++ standard syntax? -> const std::vector<int> a<% 1,2,3 %>;

Tags: c++, digraphs

I stumbled upon this code without any explanation. Googling it is a nightmare, please explain  what's this:

```
const std::vector<int> a<% 1,2,3 %>;
```

Comment: This is wild :O

Comment: c++ has never failed to suprise me

Comment: No, those are not new C++ standard, but instead rather old C legacies. [Trigraphs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) have been removed from C++17, as they can be very harmful, but *digraphs* are still accepted. Although for me, their only use is obfuscation.

Comment: Back in the olden days, some keyboards didn't have `{` and `}` keys. That made it hard to write C code. So C invented trigraphs and, later, digraphs, to make it possible for programmers with wimpy keyboards to write C code. `<%` is `{`, and `>%` is `}`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative